# Why does assigning a value to an array in a for loop result in the array having the same value for each iteration when passed to console.log()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Given the following code:

```
var tmp = [0];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
  tmp[0] = i;
  console.log(tmp);
}
```

I'd expect output of [0], [1], [2], [3], etc

But I instead get [99], [99], [99], [99], etc

Stepping through the code in a debugger (firebug) however nets me the correct result of [0], [1], [2].

Comment: Changing `console.log` to `alert` works... hmmm (didn't try `console.log` cause I don't want to enable Firebug.)

Answer (score 7):

```
console.log(tmp[0])
```

When you put console.log(tmp) you are logging the entire array object.  Firebug only creates a link to the object and then when you "look" at the object in firebug you are looking at its current state (after the for loop has completed).

Comment: That seems awfully misleading (the way the console.log works). When I step through the code, why does it behave differently?

Comment: @user414722: because when you step through, the evaluation is done each time a "step" completes. As for misleading... It's a feature: you're not logging text, you're logging an object reference, and they're all references to the same object. If you want a quick snapshot of the array, pass `tmp.slice()` to .log(); if you want a textual snapshot, just pass `tmp.toString()` to .log()

Comment: So say console.log actually did some work, the correct way of writing the for loop would be to tmp.slice(); to pass in the "snapshot" of the array?

Comment: @shasderias: what's "correct" depends entirely on what you want to happen. `console.log()` stores the reference for later use; if you want different references, you have to create them. If you're calling a routine that processes its inputs immediately rather than storing them, then you can get away with re-using the same object. I'm just explaining why the example you posted behaves the way it does... Since I don't know what you're actually trying to accomplish, I can't say how you should try to accomplish it.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. The actual problem is that I'm trying to pass the value to emit in a CouchDB map function, and truth to be told, I have no idea if it processes the input immediately. :P

But given my problem, I'm guessing that it doesn't, and thus .slice() would be correct.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting. Even without a `for` loop:

```
var tmp = [], i = 0;
tmp[0] = i;
console.log(tmp);
i++;
tmp[0] = i;
console.log(tmp);
```

produces

```
[1]
[1]
```

...as well. I was not aware that `console.log` behaved that way. Thanks to @Joshua for a good explanation.